# Create a workbook using a macro with no formulas, but still linked back to macro workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

So I built this macro workbook that creates a formatted monthly report for me.

How it works is the macro builds the report based on some criteria I define, then it copies the data portion from the worksheet "Slide" and pastes it as values to the next worksheet, "Deliverable", using this code:

```
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Slide").Range("A1"))
Range("C2", Cells(TableRows, 30)).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

then it formats and sorts everything on "Deliverable", and copies it to a new workbook using this:

```
Sheets("Deliverable").Select
Sheets("Deliverable").Copy
```

The only issue is when you open up the new workbook that only contains the copy of "Deliverable", it's still linked back to the original macro workbook and you get the security warning. I could care less about this as I know it came from me, but the report is shared outside my organization and I would prefer to avoid questions and/or hassles for my clients.

The new workbook is not macro enabled, and like I said above, contains no formulas, let alone those that reference the original workbook.

What can I do to address this?

Comment: Please post your entire code including the `.Paste` into the new workbook.  Could it be that you're using `.Paste Link:=True`? Also, have you tried recording a macro to get something like this: `ThisWorkbook.BreakLink Name:="C:\yourPath\YourFile.xls", Type:=xlExcelLinks`?

Comment: that is literally the only code that deals with copying to the Deliverable worksheet. The next line of code after paste is 'Rows("1:1").Select', and everything after I paste is literally sorting columns and adding cell formatting. No formulas of any kind.

I thought about doing the macro, but that still shows a link when you go through the file menu, so I think I was trying to get at the root of the problem.

Comment: Why don't you try `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` or (as mentioned above) break any existing link after pasting (which preserves formulas)?

Comment: I worked it out. the links were named ranges that came over with the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the links were being caused by named ranges in the workbook that came over with the copied worksheet. No formulas, just named ranges.

I added this after the worksheet copy and it took care of it.

```
Dim nm As Name 

On Error Resume Next 
For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names 
    nm.Delete 
Next 
On Error Goto 0
```